# Select part of variable in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have very little experience with perl and regex, and I have not been able to find an answer to my question, which is:

I have this command to find the pattern "package" and insert a command above the found pattern:

```
perl -i~ -p -e'/package/ and $_ = "/usr/bin/BigHonkingText $_\n$_"' script.sh
```

script.sh looks like this:

```
install -package 'Adobe Reader.pkg' -target /

install -package 'Adobe Flash.pkg' -target /
```

And after I run the perl command above it looks like this:

```
/usr/bin/BigHonkingText install -package 'Adobe Reader.pkg' -target /
install -package 'Adobe Reader.pkg' -target /

/usr/bin/BigHonkingText install -package 'Adobe Flash.pkg' -target /
install -package 'Adobe Flash.pkg' -target /
```

But I want it to look like this:

```
/usr/bin/BigHonkingText Adobe Reader.pkg
install -package 'Adobe Reader.pkg' -target /

/usr/bin/BigHonkingTextAdobe Flash.pkg
install -package 'Adobe Flash.pkg' -target /
```

What I want is that only the part within the single quote after -package is written above the line found. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the regex to extract the part between single quotes:

```
perl -i~ -pe"/package '(.*?)'/ and print qq{/usr/bin/BigHonkingText \$1\n}" script.sh
```

Comment: While `'(.*)'` is almost always wrong, it happens to work in this case. It would be better to use a safer variant like `'([^']*)'` or `'(.*?)'`.

Comment: oops, I did have a `?` in there but lost it somewhere along the way! Thanks for pointing it out @amon.